# The intersection of normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, covering-spaces

Let $G$ be a group and put
\begin{align}
\mathrm{FIA}(G)&=\{N\triangleleft G:G/N\textrm{ is finite abelian}\}.
\end{align}
**Question:** Are there some general ways to compute $\bigcap\mathrm{FIA}(G)$? What if, especially, $G$ is a free group?

---

My motivation is to get the universal covering of a (nice) topological space among finite abelian coverings, in the sense that the group above is the corresponding fundamental group.

For example, if $G$ is a finite abelian group, then $\mathrm{FIA}(G)=\{e\}$: the trivial group. Same for the case $G=\mathbb{Z}$. Another example is $\mathrm{FIA}(S_n)=A_n$ for $n\geq 5$. I have no idea for $G=F_2$ or other free groups.

Thank you!

Comment: What if the specified intersection for a free group is the commutant of the group?

Comment: This group always contains the commutator subgroup and the two are equal if and only if the abelianization of $G$ is residually finite. In particular, this is the case if the abelianization of $G$ is finitely generated or free, which is the case for all free groups.